# PHP: Identifying the local server consistently

Tags: php, apache, server, cpanel, plesk

I have a single code base which I am deploying to multiple servers.

I need to identify which server the code is running on in order to use the correct configuration information for the database and so on.

I initially tried using the DOCUMENT_ROOT and checking for the account name.

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/var/www/vhosts/SOMETHING.com/') !== false)
{ //is a specific server }
```

This works well, however I discovered that when my cron jobs are executed DOCUMENT_ROOT is empty, when initiated from Plesk.

Does a better way exist to identify the server?

I do not wish to have a server specific configuration file because the FTP sync software which ensures all files are the same across all servers does not support  excluding some files.

Plus, the servers may be running different control panels and setups, so I wish something as general as possible.

Comment: These cron jobs are responsible for runnin some console applications written in PHP right? How do you set them up? Manually on each server? In that case you can pass server name as a command line argument to the console application.

Comment: If you're running PHP from the command line, there is no web server involved. So `$_SERVER` won't return anything. There is a `hostname` command you can run from the command line. Maybe try that with `exec()` to read it through PHP?

Comment: @Nima, thanks, I didnt think of passing the server info via the cron command.

Comment: @Andy, thanks, this pointed me in the right direction as I found $_SERVER['HOME'] is the same as DOCUMENT_ROOT when the php script is called as a cron job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found $_SERVER['HOME'] via cron is the same as DOCUMENT_ROOT.

This works the same on plesk and cpanel implementations of cron.

I believe this is better than passing the parameter via the cron command because I would still need to test for it, and also would have to set cron per server, rather that handling this inside the script.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass server name as a command line argument when setting up the cron job.